# My django Fantasy Football Project. How to display the scores of other users to each user?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've built a very basic fantasy football app in django that allows a user to select and delete players for their team and then the players'individual scores are totaled up into a team score. What I'd really like to add to the app is to be able to see other users'total scores so that everyone can compare how they are doing against each other. I'm pretty new to django so I've been sitting around in my free time these past few days thinking of a way to do that, but I'm really not sure how ( or even how to ask clearly about how it's done ). One idea I had was to create a new model object that can contain a user's total team score, but I'm really not sure how to get the team score variable into that model object in the first place.

Right now, my models.py only has User and player position classes.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import datetime



class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Quarterback(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    ...rest of the player-position objects repeat...
```

I've got a function in views.py that calculates a team's total score and passes it as context for rendering. The total score is being stored in a list variable. The variable's name is "totalscore." Would there be a way to pass this "totalscore" variable to a new object model? Or, is there a completely different/much better way to do it that I'm just unaware of? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from game.views import index, show, playerchoose, delete_QB, delete_RB, delete_WR, delete_TE, delete_K

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("players", views.players, name="players"),
    path("playerinfo", views.playerinfo, name="playerinfo"),
    path('pickteam', views.pickteam, name="pickteam"),
    path('delete_QB/<int:id>', views.delete_QB, name="delete_QB"),
    path('delete_RB/<int:id>', views.delete_RB, name="delete_RB"),
    path('delete_WR/<int:id>', views.delete_WR, name="delete_WR"),
    path('delete_TE/<int:id>', views.delete_TE, name="delete_TE"),
    path('delete_K/<int:id>', views.delete_K, name="delete_K"),
    path('show',views.show, name="show"),
    path('scoreboard', views.scoreboard, name="scoreboard"), 
    path('playerchoose', views.playerchoose, name="playerchoose")
```

Comment: Show us the `urls.py` file.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sure thing. Just added it.

Comment: What is the view that shows a team?  Does it only show your own team?  If so, then it seems like one solution would be to create a view that shows _any_ team, not just your own.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, the current view only shows your own team. Create a view that shows any team? That does sound very logical. Just trying to imagine how to implement that.

Comment: It should be very similar to the existing view, except that the ID of the team to be displayed would be passed in as part of the URL, instead of obtained from the `User` model of the current logged-in user.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it sounds like you don't yet have a `Team` model. This should probably be your next step. Something like this would be a good idea:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
      settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
      on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    quarter_back = models.ForeignKey(
      QuarterBack,
      on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    # other players here
```

(I'm sorry, I don't know much about american football so don't know if you have one or many quarterbacks etc.)

If the models for all your different player positions are the same, it might be better just to have one `FootballPlayer` class, and then add a property to describe the position to that model, something like this:

```
class FootballPlayer(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True
    )  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

(Note it's better practice to use `settings.USER_AUTH_MODEL` rather than `User`).

Then you could use a many-to-many relationship between players and teams. You can add a method to your `Team` class to get the total score:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def score(self):
        # logic to calculate total score here
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I did try a choice field before but it caused me a lot of headache when I tried to do the delete part of CRUD. For now, I'm planning to keep individual object models for individual player positions. A bit crude, but works in this case. I built a Team model as you suggested. Problem I'm having now is calculating the team score. My player models don't contain a score field as they will be updated through the api. I'm working on comparing the players in the Team model to score data in a variable and storing the results in a score variable...trying to at least.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for aggregation / annotation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

I think it will be something like

```
my_users = User.objects.annotate(total_score=Sum('quarterback__score'))
```

If you now put my_users in a view, each one would have a property "total_score" you could compare them to each other with.

---

Edit for your comment:

If I were you I would probably have my models like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Team(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)

class Player(models.Model):
    QUARTERBACK =  'QB'
    BALLRUNNER = 'BR'
    BALLKICKER = 'BK'
    PLAYER_POSITION_CHOICES = [
        (QUARTERBACK = 'Quarterback'),
        (BALLRUNNER, 'Ballrunner'),
        (BALLKICKER, 'Ballkicker'),
    ]
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, ...)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    position = models.CharField(choices=PLAYER_POSITION_CHOICES)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you have `Team.objects.annotate(total_score=Sum('player__score'))`
You can also put in your own functions inside the object.
Like `Team` could have something like

```
def total_score(self):
    score = 0
    for player in self.players:
        score = score + player.score
    return score
```

Might not be the most efficient way to do stuff, but remember that it's a possibility.

See choices https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices for documentation on the changes on the Player model.

Comment: Seeing as there are several players to a team, could you add several arguments to that? For example  User.objects.annotate(total_score=Sum('quarterback__score', 'runningback_score' ...etc))

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm not sure if it's possible to do like you asked in your comment. You could try, but I would add Team as an object either way. Biggest change I made was the change on the Player model. Unless there are attributes that require different models for the different positions I would put them all in the same model.

Comment: Tim has worded his answer better than I. But it looks like we're thinking the same thing.